# linux command sed only show line 1 to 2 not work

Tags: sed

I use sed to show the first 2 lines of the file 'sed.txt',but it does not work:
the file sed.txt is like:

```
$cat sed.txt
1
2
3
4
```

use sed command:

```
$sed -e '1,2p' sed.txt
1
1
2
2
3
4
```

the line 3 and 4 is also printed,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed -n` if you don't want sed to print every processed line. Or, tell sed to remove the lines that weren't selected:

```
sed -e '1,2!d'
```